# Using leaflet.offline in react Typescript not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-hooks, react-leaflet

I am trying to add offline functionality to leaflet map, im using React-leaflet and leaflet.offline: https://github.com/allartk/leaflet.offline/blob/master/docs/api.md

I am importing it like the documentation `import * from 'leaflet.offline/TileManager';`

I also imported leaflet like this because of type issues: `declare const L: any;`

My issued code is this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const tileLayerOffline = new L.tileLayer
      .offline('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data {attribution.OpenStreetMap}',
        subdomains: 'abc',
        minZoom: 13,
      });
    tileLayerOffline.addTo(map);
  })
```

Now my error is:

> TS1005: 'from' expected. on the import of leaflet offline.

if i remove **new** from L.tileLayer i get

> Uncaught TypeError: L.tileLayer.offline is not a function

Anyone know of any working react leaflet offline implementation with the new react hooks? or know the solution to this?

Comment: Have you made any progress with this?

Comment: I have been able to make the tileLayer component work, but the save controls is my issue now. @kboul